# Athena: chain query to same table until all values are found

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have below query:

```
select a_id, b_id, c_id
from t1
where b_id='ejdhehgke-5154-jshgqwjhw-BDAA-49D15E214944'
group by a_id, b_id, c_id limit 20
```

Then I have to query from the results of the above query again as:

```
select a_id, b_id, c_id
from t1
where b_id='ejdhehgke-5154-jshgqwjhw-BDAA-49D15E214944' or c_id='qwkgkjqw' or c_id='ajqwhgjqw'
group by a_id, b_id, c_id
limit 20
```

and again for third time:

```
select a_id, b_id, c_id
from t1
where 
b_id='ejdhehgke-5154-jshgqwjhw-BDAA-49D15E214944' or c_id='qwkgkjqw' or c_id='ajqwhgjqw'
a_id='qwhgqwghiwq', b_id='qwjygjqwgejew'
group by a_id, b_id, c_id limit 20
```

How to combine all this into one query?

Comment: (1) Your queries are not all syntactically correct.  (2) The queries could return the same rows.  (3) You need to explain the logic you are trying to implement.  (4) Without an `order by`, `limit` returns arbitrary rows that can change between runs.

Comment: @GordonLinoff could you elaborate on (1) please?
(2) yes and also null or '' or '000' which I filter-out
(3) So for now, i have programmed it with a script, which starts with any of the one id value, and runs the same query over and over until there is no new id found in any of the three id's
(4) Group by: so it return unique rows. Limit: I had put it there to limit the results in case i made a mistake and it returns way too many results.

So i am hoping if it can be all integrated into one query, with joins.

Comment: . . (1) You have a comma in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That was a typo, sorry